# Tag 'closed' nominated for disappearance

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags

We've got a tag, [closed](/questions/tagged/closed). It is applied to a heterogenous set of topics: closed source, closed network connections, etc. Do we want to get rid of it?

Comment: I see no redeeming value in this tag. Also at 15 questions it's not hard to dispose of.

Answer (score 2):

I've killed off the [closed](/questions/tagged/closed) tag, but there is a much bigger problem...

The [close](/questions/tagged/close) tag also exists, and it's running a good 800 questions strong, and follows the same pattern of ambiguity.